# Can I do propensity score reweigh in R?

Tags: r

I have propensity scores and the treatment dummy in my data-frame already, but I couldn't find the right way to use the propensity score to reweigh my wage distribution in my data.

Is there any package I can use for it? Thank you

Comment: If you just want to weight each observation by its propensity score (or do Inverse Probability of Treatment Weighting) then, for example, with the`lm` function you would do `lm(outcome ~ treatment_dummy + x1 + x2, weights=ps, data=my_data)`, where `ps` is the column with the propensity scores or the IPTW values.

Comment: My goal is not to find the treatment effect, but set both control and treatment group have the same mean of propensity score, then compares their kernel density. Therefore, I am not sure about can I do it with R

Comment: Check out the `Matchit` and `Matching` packages.